# Highstock: How to change flag fill colour on click

Tags: colors, highcharts, flags

I would like to change a flag fill colour when a user clicks it. I tried to accomplish this with:

```js
plotOptions : {
   flags: {
  events: {
     click: function(event){
     alert("I am clicked");
     this.fillColor='orange';
  }
     },
  }
},
```

The alert message is displayed but the flag fill colour stays the same.
Can anyone point me in a right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Point.update) in the click event and modify fillColor parameter.

```
plotOptions: {
            flags: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click:function() {
                            this.update({
                                fillColor: 'red'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ztq7cq3k/